# Fullcalendar - limit selectable to a single day

Tags: fullcalendar

By default if you enable the 'selectable' attribute it will allow you to click and drag and select several days. I would like to only allow the user to select a single day, not drag over multiple. Is there a way to have 'selectable' enabled, but disable the dragging feature that comes along with it?

Answer (score 20):

If you want to limit highlight to a single day in agenda week view you can use following:

```
  selectConstraint:{
      start: '00:01', 
      end: '23:59', 
    },
```

if you want to limit the event you can use

```
eventConstraint:{
      start: '00:00', 
      end: '24:00', 
    },
```

Comment: can you give an example that it works only on week view not on month view?

Comment: @saurabhgoyal795 in calendar options set 'defaultView' to 'agendaWeek' and you'll see only week

Comment: This does not work for me, I am unable to select any dates now. `selectable: true` is set

Answer (score 5):

in the select callback, adding the following does the trick: 
(fullcalendar 2 using moment.js)

```
if (start.add('days', 1).date() != end.date() )
  $scope.eventCal.fullCalendar('unselect');
```

resources:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/unselect_method/

Answer (score 3):

You can select a single date or time by passing fullcalendar's 'select' method to the dayClick event listener:

```
$('#myCalendar').fullcalendar({
    dayClick: function(date,jsEvent,view) {
        $('#myCalendar').fullcalendar('select', date);
    }
});
```

Note you will also need to fire the 'unselect' method on your next callback (or dayClick).

Comment: This works great when you also set `selectable: false`.

Comment: I did not need to use unselect. Maybe they changed something?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `selectAllow`?

Start by converting the `start` and `end` times to seconds. Compare that to the number of seconds in a day.

**Working Solution Without Using Moment.js:**

```
selectAllow: function (e) {
   if (e.end.getTime() / 1000 - e.start.getTime() / 1000 <= 86400) {
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, even though if you start at 11am on a given day, you can still select the next day until 10am since the total time will be less than 24 hours, so this method does not really address the OP need.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration setting worked for me on FullCalendar v5:

```
selectAllow: function(selectionInfo) {
    let startDate = selectionInfo.start;
    let endDate = selectionInfo.end;
    endDate.setSeconds(endDate.getSeconds() - 1);  // allow full day selection
    if (startDate.getDate() === endDate.getDate()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply :

```js
selectAllow: function (selectInfo) {
    return selectInfo.end.diff(selectInfo.start, 'days') == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me using the selectAllow option like this worked

```
selectAllow: function(selectionInfo) {
        // Don't allow creation of events over more than 1 day
        return moment(selectionInfo.start).utcOffset(false).isSame(moment(selectionInfo.end).subtract(1, 'second').utcOffset(false), 'day');
    },
```

I used utcOffset(false) because for whatever reason it doesn't work reliably without it and I used subtract(1, 'second') because the end date is inclusive, so without it you can't select the end of the day

Answer (score 0):

This will be executed only when the user selects a day

```
// ...
select: function(start, end){
    if(moment(start._d).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')==moment(end._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD')){
            //  just select one day
    }
},
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do this using `validRange`:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange

Answer (score -1):

Not at this time: the range of selectable days can not be customized without modifying the source.

Comment: has anything changed...meaning that has been added the feature to select only one day?