# How to split single day in column in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to split single day of Fullcalendar view in multi column.
Some thing like this. How can I achieve this ? 
[image]

This question partially related to this one [Fullcalendar - limit selectable to a single day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071943/fullcalendar-limit-selectable-to-a-single-day)

Thanks , Any kind of help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: When i add multiple resource, i gets some cosmetic issue. see this link http://prntscr.com/6rx76y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some help here by this link:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490

which led me to

https://github.com/AbleTech/fullcalendar

I took this fork of fullcalendar and was able to replace the 1.5.3 that i was using and then used the resourceDay view.

Comment: When i add multiple resource, i gets some cosmetic issue. see this link http://prntscr.com/6rx76y

Answer (score 5):

I just published my solution at https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns. It currently does not allow labels ("Joe Bloggs", "Alan Black" etc. in your screenshot) but has the advantage that it is *not* a clone of FullCalendar, so you have more freedom to use it with a FullCalendar version you like. It's very basic at the moment but feature requests are welcome.