# How to make past date unselectable in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

Problem is, how to disable selectable on PAST DATES in fullcalendar's month/week view.

I want to user not allowed to click/select the on past dates.

[image]

**Here is some googled code snippet I am trying to implement on event rendering:**

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: false,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var appdate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('<?php echo $DPFormat; ?>', new Date(start));
        jQuery('#appdate').val(appdate);
        jQuery('#AppFirstModal').show();
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view)
    {
        var view = 'month' ;
       if(event.start.getMonth() !== view.start.getMonth()) { return false; }
    },
```

But its not working though.

I tried bellow CSS too and this help me to hide past date text only, but selectable is still working on pastdate box.

```
.fc-other-month .fc-day-number {
     display:none;
}
```

I am really stuck with this problem. Please someone help me out. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have done this in my fullcalendar and it's working perfectly.

you can add this code in your select function.

```
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if(check < today)
    {
        // Previous Day. show message if you want otherwise do nothing.
        // So it will be unselectable
    }
    else
    {
        // Its a right date
        // Do something
    }
  },
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Here am using this. Thanks. appointzilla.com/wordpress-google/?page_id=8

Comment: `formatDate()` seems to be gone in the latest version. Use instead: `var check = start._d.toJSON().slice(0,10);` `var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);` to get the dates as yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: start and end are already moment,js objects so you can just do:
`var check = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

Comment: because of moment formate it will now work with this
`var selectedDate = moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD');`
`var todayDate = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');`
`if(selectedDate >= todayDate){}`

Comment: I am using full calendar 4 version. It works.       select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var selectedDate = moment(start.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD'); 
   var todayDate = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD'); 
   if(selectedDate >= todayDate){
          addAvailability(start.startStr, start.endStr);

   } else {
    alert('Previous date is not allowed');
   }   
  },

Comment: @Mausami i have to check time also with date then?

Comment: This is the best answer, it keeps the calendar looking nice, while isValid makes the calendar look like dukey stain

Answer (score 32):

I like this approach:

```
select: function(start, end) {
    if(start.isBefore(moment())) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will essentially disable selection on times before "now".

[Unselect method](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselect_method/)

Comment: I assume it will fail when selecting the "allDay" slot of the current day.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011150/1214902), I've found the solution below:

```
$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    selectConstraint: {
        start: $.fullCalendar.moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
        end: $.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'month')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

The old answers to this question are ok...

However, the official documentation suggests a new, more concise solution:

First set the day you want to be the lower bound

```
 var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Then include the range using `validRange`. Simply omit the `end` date.

```
 validRange: {
    start: today
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

I have tried this approach, works well.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   defaultView: 'month',
   selectable: true,
   selectAllow: function(select) {
      return moment().diff(select.start, 'days') <= 0
   }
})
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 8):

In fullcalendar 3.9, you might prefer the [`validRange function parameter`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) :

```
validRange: function(nowDate){
    return {start: nowDate} //to prevent anterior dates
},
```

Drawback: this also hides events before that datetime

Answer (score 7):

In FullCalendar v3.0, there is the property [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow):

```
selectAllow: function(info) {
    if (info.start.isBefore(moment()))
        return false;
    return true;          
}
```

Comment: and if you want to allow from today's date to any future date :
Change if condition as :-

if ( info.start.isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days')) )

Answer (score 5):

You can combine:

-hide text by CSS as mentioned in question

-[disable PREV button on current month](http://www.theantichris.com/2013/01/disable-previous-month-navigation-in-fullcalendar/)

-check date on dayClick/eventDrop etc:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var now = new Date();
    if (date.setHours(0,0,0,0) < now.setHours(0,0,0,0)){
        alert('test');
    }
    else{
         //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am currently using

Also added the .add() function so the user cannot add an event at the same hour

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
               if(end.isBefore(moment().add(1,'hour').format())) {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
               return false;
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var start_date= $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'YYYY-MM-DD');

var today_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

if(check < today)
{
    alert("Back date event not allowed ");
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

below is the solution i'm using now:

```
        select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
            if (moment().diff(start, 'days') > 0) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                // or display some sort of alert
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a long program, just try this.

```
checkout.setMinSelectableDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());    
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

Gives us the current date.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `validRange` option.

`validRange: {
  start: Date.now(),
  end: Date.now() + (7776000) // sets end dynamically to 90 days after now (86400*90)
}`

Answer (score 0):

In Fullcalendar i achieved it by dayClick event. I thought it is the simple way to do it.

Here is my code..

```
 dayClick: function (date, cell) {
              var current_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
              // date.format() returns selected date from fullcalendar
              if(current_date <= date.format()) {
                //your code
              }
            }
```

Hope it helps past and future dates will be unselectable..

Answer (score 0):

if any one of answer is not work for you please try this i hope its work for you.

```
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {                

              var check = formatDate(start.startStr);
              var today = formatDate(new Date());

              if(check < today)
              {
                 console.log('past');                     
              }
              else
              {                    
                console.log('future');
              }
}
```

and also create function for date format as below

```
function formatDate(date) {
      var d = new Date(date),
          month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
          day = '' + d.getDate(),
          year = d.getFullYear();

      if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
      if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

      return [year, month, day].join('-');
  }
```

i have tried all above question but not work for me

you can try this if any other answer work for you.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add this if statement

```js
 select(info) {
      if (moment(info.start).format() > moment().format()) {
       //your code here
      } else {
        toast.error("Please select valid date");
      }
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For FullCalendar React (Disable past day completely):

```
selectAllow={c => (moment().diff(c.start, 'hours') <= 0)}
```