# Not allowing selection of past dates through FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This question was asked quite a while ago here:
[How to make past date unselectable in fullcalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978629/how-to-make-past-date-unselectable-in-fullcalendar)

But FullCalendar has now entered a completely different version using Moment instead of it's own date formatting.

How would one achieve a selectable calendar that doesn't allow selection of dates before today?

**EDIT: Nailed it!**

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var selectionStart = moment(start); 
            var today = moment(); // passing moment nothing defaults to today

            if (selectionStart < today) { 
                $('#YourCalendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
            else {
             // do stuff
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would be more appropriate to post your answer on the original post. This is still a duplicate question. People will find that original question and if your answer is the more relevant, will be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make past date unselectable in fullcalendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978629/how-to-make-past-date-unselectable-in-fullcalendar)