# Jquery: FullCalendar - set the starting day and finish day of the whole Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Dear afternoon to everyone,

I'm currently working on a web-app to organize events. I'm using express and mongoDB.

The main idea is that a user can create an "event" Object with a startDate and endDate field and then other users can click on the calendar to say when they can. 
So i choose the FullCalendar, but i want to display only the day between the startDate and the endDate. Let's make an example.

Assuming my event is described as follow

```
{title: "Hey!",
startDate: 05/31/2016 2:20 PM,
endDate: 06/03/2016 2:20 PM
}
```

I want that my calendar will show ONLY these 4 days. Do you guys know how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at custom views? They allow you to set the duration like below.

```
var startDate = '2014-11-12';
var numberOfDays = 4;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        center: 'customDays' // buttons for switching between views
    },
    defaultView: 'customDays',
    views: {
        customDays: {
            type: 'basicWeek',
            duration: { days: numberOfDays },
            buttonText: 'Custom Days'
        }
    },
    defaultDate: startDate
});
```

[Fullcalendar View Documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/)

It would appear you can't do it in the month view but you can in the basicWeek view, check out the example in [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ticuqa/edit?js,output)

Comment: if i understand correctly here you are creating a new view, but you aren't change the others. I need a way to disable the others day

Comment: I have updated the answer, you could have buttons for whichever views you want in the header and also set the default view to the view you want.

Comment: can you give me an example for a month view? Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoZ I have updated the answer again, when you set the duration it actually hides the other days. This may not be what you were looking for. If you just want the days disabled couldn't you use some css to make them look inactive and then when a user clicks on a day check it's a valid day before executing any code? Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978629/how-to-make-past-date-unselectable-in-fullcalendar

Comment: Yeah something like that, but the main problem with that code is that i need to click on the day and i can't change the css before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it. I can use the function dayRender as below

```
 dayRender: function( date, cell ) {
      if(date.diff(event.startDate,'days') < 0 || date.diff(event.endDate,'days') > 0){
          $(cell).addClass('disable');
          console.log(cell)
      }
    }
```