# Is it possible to make some events unable on FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I wanna make 'clickable = false' or 'enable = false' for events before today, went through docs of FullCalendar but couldn't find.

Is there any feature of FullCalendar for making it or should i find a JS solution?

Comment: take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978629/how-to-make-past-date-unselectable-in-fullcalendar

Comment: You could simply check if the date has passed in your onclick function. And don't run if it is passed.