# FullCalendar - Show dates in past

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar and i want to make older dates visible but not clickable.

Also i am using `validRange` property and it is working well, but it only makes them not visible.

FullCalendar version 5.

Here my codes:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridWeek',
            locale: 'de',
            timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin',
            hiddenDays: [0, 6],
            validRange: {
                start: tomorrow()
            },
            events: 'http://rendezvous.wm/api/available-times/<?php echo $departmentID; ?>',
            headerToolbar: {
                start: 'title', // will normally be on the left. if RTL, will be on the right
                center: '',
                end: 'today prev,next' // will normally be on the right. if RTL, will be on the left
            },
            displayEventEnd: true,
            eventTimeFormat: {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                hour12: false
            },
            eventClick: function (info) {
                window.location.href = "<?php echo WP_HOME . '/terminvereinbaren-details?'; ?>department_id=<?php echo $departmentID
                  . '&event_start=';?>" + info.event.start.toISOString()+"&event_end="+info.event.end.toISOString()
            },
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

and here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You could put some validation into your `dateClick()` or `select()` handler that alerts the user to an invalid selection (or does nothing). Example if you view source here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo

Comment: several answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978629/how-to-make-past-date-unselectable-in-fullcalendar

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow - just tell it to return false for any dates before today.