# How can i disable full calendar Sorting & Dragging functionlity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am stuck in `fullcalendar js`. First, I want to display title according to my sorting & disable calendar sorting. Second, how can I disable calendar `dragging` functionality?

Here is a link to my current work:   http://everybodylovesmonkeys.com/_clients/thunderroad/calendar

Comment: you should set `editable` to `false`. [read here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/editable/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can i change or disable calendar sorting, so my sorted array list works..

Comment: [Fullcalendar - limit selectable to a single day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071943/fullcalendar-limit-selectable-to-a-single-day) answers the second question

Comment: What do you mean by calendar sorting, I can't see any sorting on that page?

Comment: If two events are occurring in same day, by default full calendar sort Events(array) according title but i want to disable that sorting & display my array list.. For eg- here u see 2 title on june 2, i want the anil group to display first. link- http://everybodylovesmonkeys.com/_clients/thunderroad/calendar