# FullCalendar.js how to restrict date select to one day on Month View

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar.js](https://fullcalendar.io/) for a date selector on my web page.

I want to limit the range of selectable dates on my full calendar widget to `one day only` (the default is to drag for multiple dates, or click for a single date). I'd like to effectively disable the drag functionality for selecting multiple dates, either by:

1. Disabling the native drag event (probably incorrect)
2. Restrict the date range of selectable dates to one day (this feels more sensible)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071943/fullcalendar-limit-selectable-to-a-single-day) has answers on how to limit date selection to one day using the **week view**  by specifying `start` and `end` in the `selectConstraint` option. However, the same solution does not work for the **month view**.

How can I limit the date selection range to one day for month view?

**My Code:**

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    selectable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next ',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    validRange: {
      start: today
    },
    selectConstraint:{
      start: '00:01', 
      end: '23:59', 
    },
    dateClick: function(info) {
      custom_date = true;
      $("#start_date").val(info.dateStr);
      $("#end_date").val(info.dateStr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you can use the `selectAllow` function.

First convert the date strings into seconds with `getTime() / 1000`.

Compare the start time and the end time to the number of seconds in a day `86400`. If it is less than or equal to that number, only one day was selected.

**Working code:**

```
selectAllow: function (e) {
   if (e.end.getTime() / 1000 - e.start.getTime() / 1000 <= 86400) {
       return true;
   }
}
```